# PHP socket with jQuery/AJAX user-end

Tags: php, ajax, sockets, jquery, cross-browser

I've been working on sockets, generally in PHP for a while. Currently I have a PHP client for connecting to a chat server, and output every each data sent from server it's connected to.

To explain that in a wider matter, I accomplished this using flush() function in PHP to write out every each buffer waiting in the loop. Buffer reader is withing a while where the condition is the status of the connection socket. But this matters less.

Now to what I want to accomplish. I want to keep socket handling to server side and data from server outputted to client, via AJAX/jQuery. So far, my researches always returned me HTML5 WebSocket and node.js, however, I "have to" be real picky about this, as for users of this, my minimal dependency might be:

- WinXP IE6 users(Already disables jQuery, even)
- Users without JAVA/Flash installed

So I have to think of possibilities in this, which is why I can't use a Flash/Java backend or a new technology like WebSockets, and neither I want to handle server stuff in the client. **I really hate to be stuck in old technology but for this it's a must.**

As I was searching around, I found this one being as similiar to my needs.

[Is PHP socket a viable option for making PHP jQuery based chat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3267324/is-php-socket-a-viable-option-for-making-php-jquery-based-chat)

And to quick review the answers, they all point to one direction, PHP multi-process and memory eating. I know this is a minus, but it's the best I can take for now. But yet still, there'll be timeout disconnects for inactive connections within a certain delay, and extension of the delay if wanted. So I'm not much onto this one.

Secondly, the last answer pointing to "Ajax Chat Application Tutorial", I made an overall review but whoa, writing each line into an html file and re-including it each time, that is which I could do without using an extra file but, is it really necessary? Plus re-reading the file from server side, and re-importing the whole read file into document every each time, isn't that just worse for "both sides"?

Either ways that's about it, I wasn't able to come to a conclusion for a while, and it happened, here I am again. (:P) Waiting for your answers/suggestions/ideas, thanks by now.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

There is server software available that specializes in such matters. Is called a push server/service. There's for example APE (http://www.ape-project.org/); according to their website, it's compatible with all web browsers and they even got a demo chat there. I'd suggest you to go for that solution.